# Wrong datetime format conversion in GridView

Tags: asp.net, gridview, date-formatting

I have `GridView` and I'm populating it with the data.

There is a `DateTime` field in database in `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss.mmm` format.
When displayed in `GridView`, the following is displayed: `2016-04-06T00:00:00`

How can I convert it to something like dd/mm/yyyy 05:23 PM - European format.

Currently, when populating grid I have the following:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblDate" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Holiday", "{0:dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm tt}") %>'></asp:Label>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does your grid currently display?

Comment: I have that in my question

Comment: So the format isn't applied?

Comment: Yes. It is not applied